# Shoot first, ask questions later - Semicolon or comma

Tags: idioms, punctuation, commas, semicolons

In the idiom "shoot first, ask questions later", should the clauses be separated by a comma or semicolon? There are many derivations from that idiom to the point at which it has become a trope, but I'm still not clear on what is the correct punctuation.

I most frequently seen it written with a comma, but I've seen others such as semicolons and em-dashes (definitely a stylistic choice for the latter).

[Idiom dictionaries seem to prefer the comma](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Shoot+first%2C+ask+questions+later), but I would like to understand why.

Comment: No such thing as correct punctuation in English. It’s all a matter of style. Of course there, is incorrect punctuation.

Comment: If there is incorrect punctuation, there must also be correct punctuation.

Comment: @Naomi - stated differently, you can't sort punctuation neatly into 'correct' and 'incorrect'

Comment: The problem is that the comma leaves many nit-pickers commatose.

Comment: There is a spectrum of punctuation usage in English. At each end are definites : 'correct' and 'incorrect'. In the middle is the 'style choice' area, where opinions and tastes differ but none has the right to dogmatically assert control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the dreaded comma splice. That's what happens when you have two independent clauses, no coordinating conjunction, and a comma—the weakling of punctuation marks—trying to separate them.

[The Chicago Manual of Style notes](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0090.html):

> Some readers will be distracted by it; some will consider it
>   incorrect; a few will take it as one more sign that civilization is
>   coming to an end. However, as Bryan Garner writes in Garner's Modern
>   American Usage: "Most usage authorities accept comma splices when (1)
>   the clauses are short and closely related, (2) there is no danger of a
>   miscue, and (3) the context is informal."

[Professor Tina Blue elaborates](http://grammartips.homestead.com/spliceok.html):

> If the independent clauses are very short, especially if the subject
>   is the same for both clauses, then a comma splice is probably
>   acceptable. . . . When fairly short independent clauses express
>   contrast, a comma splice is often the most effective way to punctuate
>   the sentence. This is especially true if the first clause makes a
>   negative statement, the second an affirmative one, or if the first
>   clause is affirmative, and the second is negative (as in one form of
>   question).

.

Your clauses certainly qualify as short, closely related, informal, same-subject, and contrasty:

> *Shoot first, ask questions later.*

And Julius Caesar's been getting away with this since forever:

> *I came, I saw, I conquered.*

But if you're worried that your usage authority will take this as a sign that civilization is coming to an end, you have many other options:

> *Shoot first—ask questions later.*
>
> *Shoot first (ask questions later).*
>
> *Shoot first; ask questions later.*
>
> *Shoot first, and ask questions later.*
>
> *Shoot first. Ask questions later.*

.

Further reading:

[Comma Splices and Run-On Sentences](http://cmosshoptalk.com/2019/04/16/comma-splices-and-run-on-sentences/)

.

Comment: Answer first ; collect points later. (+1).

Answer (score 4):

The idiom refers to snap-judgment action, quickness of resolve. Of your three punctuation choices: comma, semicolon, or em-dash, the comma exerts the least amount of force towards slowing the reading of the phrase. It results in a cadence/tempo most congruent with the underlying idea.